# List commits from all remote branches except one

Tags: git, github, version-control

Say I have multiple remote branches..

```
origin/master
origin/feature-branch-01
origin/feature-branch-02
origin/release-branch
```

On 'master' the main development takes place, on release we merge master-commits by cherry-picking them (and maybe create "real" commits for bugfixing) and in the two feature branches new features are developed.

Being on master branch, I want to list all commits from master and feature branches but not from the release-branch. If I run..

```
git --no-pager log --since=01.12.2015 --oneline
```

I only get the commits on master (or whatever branch I am on). If I run..

```
git --no-pager log --since=01.11.2015 --oneline --all
```

I get all the commits from all remote branches. 
What can I do here to get all except the release branch?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding `--not release-branch` at the end of your last `git log` command.

Comment: I was afraid it was that easy :) Thank you, that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the `--not` switch, which the [`git-log` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) describes as follows:

> ```
> --not
>            Reverses the meaning of the ^ prefix (or lack thereof) for all
>            following revision specifiers, up to the next --not.
> ```

Accordingly, adding `--not release-branch` at the end of your `git log` command, like so

```
git --no-pager log --since=01.11.2015 --oneline --all --not release-branch
```

will list all the relevant commits, excluding those only reachable from `release-branch`.